# Analytical definite integral yields wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, singularity

I'm trying to perform an analytical definite integral.

```
2/c*(Integrate[(r^2 + (M*a)^2)/(
r^2 - 2*M*r + (M*a)^2), {r, rp + del, rmax}])
```

Here are all the parameters:

```
a = 0.67;
rp = M*(1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2]) ;
rm = M*(1 - Sqrt[1 - a^2]);
del = (Sqrt[1 - a^2] lp^2)/(4*M*(1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2]));

rmax = M*2.179066850567806 ;
lp = 1.61622837*10^-35;
M = k*67.58*1.9891*10^30;
c = 299792458 ; G = 6.67408*10^-11; k = G /c^2;
```

The integral either returns a value without complaining, or fails completely.
Since the integral is analytical I have done in myself which gives:

```
2/c ((rmax - rp - del) + ((rp^2 + (a*M)^2)/(rp - rm))* 
Log[(rmax - rp)/del] - ((rm^2 + (a*M)^2)/(rp - rm))* 
Log[(rmax - rm)/(rp - rm + del)])
```

Which upon evaluation returns the value: 0.288844165445997.
This value is very close to the correct value (I have a source so I can compare). The integrate command though, gives either crap or does not work.
As you can see if you run the code, del is an extremely small number leading to the lower integration limit rp + del being very close to rp. The problem is, I suspect, the fact that rp is actually a singular point of the integral making it very hard for mathematica to do this correctly without further specifications or precision etc.?

How can I make this work? Any suggestions? What is the problem?

Could it be the precision that makes the integral not work, and also makes the result in the analytically evaluated expression not be completely right?

Comment: Yes it appears to be a precision problem. One solution: Change all your decimal approximations to exact rational numbers, quit the kernel and restart, do the Integrate and then N[YourResult, 64] gives you 0.2888441654459968...

Answer (score 4):

The integral can be done in closed form:

```
Integrate[(r^2 + (M*a)^2)/(r^2 - 2*M*r + (M*a)^2), r]
```

[image]

So all you need do is plug in the various values. Your constants have a very large variability (from 10^-35 to 10^30) so you are likely to 
have numerical issues with floating point numbers.